# Can I add multiple VAST tags in a single Player, means, if one vast ad has failed to load,then take the other one

Tags: javascript, html, video.js, vast

I have integrated IMA SDK Plugin for Video.js HTML5 player for my website. I followed this link https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima. Now the test Vast ad is coming.
But I need to know how I can add multiple VAST tags in a single player. I mean if one vast ad has failed to load, then take and load the other one.
I searched on the internet but couldn't seen any answer for this.
Is there any Waterfalls or fallback plugins available for Video.js for Vast?

Answer (score 0):

By default the plugin does not support this. However one could add multiple VAST urls; you will have to write your own verification mechanism to check to see if the ad is available then reinitialize the VAST plugin and the player.  The down side to the plugin is if there isno VAST ad the player will autoplay one should also account for this too.

Check out this code here, I use two VAST ad urls one as a preroll and another as a postroll. I destroy the player, recreate, and reinitialize it to create a seamless experience. http://codepen.io/JaminQuimby/pen/yNaOwz/
    `plugins: {
  ads:{},
  vast: {
preroll:"http://videoads.theonion.com/vast/270.xml?url="+window.location+"&description_url="+document.title+"&correlator=" + new Date().getTime(),
postroll:"http://videoads.theonion.com/vast/268.xml?url="+window.location+"&description_url="+document.title+"&correlator=" + new Date().getTime(),
    url: ""
}},`

Answer (score 0):

The VAST tag spec also does this with the `<Wrapper>` element. By default, if one video fails to play (the parent element) the child will play if included.

https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/VAST_Samples/blob/master/VAST%204.0%20Samples/Wrapper_Tag-test.xml